# Método no soportado en laravel

Tags: laravel, rutas

Estoy intentando guardar unos datos en laravel y no consigo hacerlo y no entiendo la razón a ver si me pueden ayudar!

Estoy creando un registro de usuarios. Acá el formulario

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register-user') }}">
@csrf
...
</form>
```

En el archivo de rutas tengo lo siguiente:

```
Route::post('registeruser', [Controllers\IndexController::class, 'registerUser']) -> name('register-user');
```

y por último el controlador:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function registerUser(Request $request)
    {

        $request -> validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'years' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'category' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'city' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'province' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'country' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);

        $newUser = new Models\User;
        $newUser -> name = $request -> name;
        $newUser -> lastname = $request -> lastname;
        $newUser -> years = $request -> years;
        $newUser -> category = $request -> category;
        $newUser -> city = $request -> city;
        $newUser -> province = $request -> province;
        $newUser -> country = $request -> country;
        $newUser -> email = $request -> email;
        $newUser -> password = Hash::make($request -> password);
        $newUser -> type = 2;

        $newUser -> save();

        return view('web.registro-exitoso');

    }
}
```

Según entiendo, el formulario lo tengo como POST, y en la ruta también, pero cuando lo envío me da el error **The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**

Alguien que me de una mano!? :/

Rutas

[image: rutas]

Comment: Intenta modificar la línea de la ruta por `Route::post('register-user', 
 IndexController@registerUser) -> name('register-user');`

Comment: @NoobDev es laravel 8, no funciona con esa sintaxis.

Comment: Ejecuta en consola el comando `php artisan route:list` a ver que metodo te arroja esa ruta y luego me dices.

Comment: @ElianMiranda actualizado con las rutas

Comment: @BetaM lo intenté pero no resultó. En local todo me funciona correctamente pero en el server online me da el error. El servidor es NGINX.

Comment: podrias intentar limpiando el cache, porque si te funciona en local no creo que haya inconveniente, php artisan route:clear